# Tensorflow custom_gradient with non-tensor arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-decorators, gradient

Playing with tensorflow's @tf.custom_gradient decorator I always had trouble, when one of the arguments of the function (can be debated whether this is an op) was meant to be immutable and I cannot (or do not want to) define its gradient contribution.
Since there does not seem to be a way to tell tensorflow anything about its input properties, I resided to the following solution, which I think might be useful for others. Here is the example for defining the Poisson-base loss. Only "fwd" is a tensor and all other arguments are not:

```
def Loss_Poisson(fwd,meas,Bg=0.05, checkPos=False):
    meanmeas=np.mean(meas)
    if checkPos:
        fwd=((tf.sign(fwd) + 1)/2)*fwd
    @tf.custom_gradient
    def BarePoisson(myfwd):
        def grad(dy):
            mygrad=dy*(1.0 - meas/(myfwd+Bg))/meas.size  # the size accounts for the mean operation (rather than sum)
            return mygrad
        totalError = tf.reduce_mean((myfwd+Bg-meas) - meas * tf.log((myfwd+Bg)/(meas+Bg)))  
        return totalError,grad    
    return BarePoisson(fwd)/meanmeas
```

The trick is to use an inner function, which has only one (tensor) argument and sneakingly uses the other immutable arguments from the outer function. This way the @tf.custom_gradient decorator is blind to those. In a test this worked well.
Probably a cleaner solution would assert that non of those (mean,Bg and checkPos) is actually a tensor, since this would potentially lead to wrong gradients.

Are there any (better) alternatives to such a hack?

Comment: I _think_ you can return `None` to say "this gradient is not defined" (at least I think that is what TensorFlow does with ops that do not have a gradient).